# deploymentName Paramater Deploy.ps1 Mandatory but not used?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I just clicked together a new "Azure Database for MySQL" resource in the gui of portal.azure.com. I downloaded the template.zip and deployed this package by using the deploy.ps1.

```
Deploy.ps1 -subscriptionId [DirectoryID] -resourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -resourceGroupLocation "West Europe" -deploymentName "Test_Deployment"
```

Deployment went fine but the deploymentName didn't catch. Name in the GUI was "template". When I analysed the deploy.ps1 script I realized the paramater deploymentName is mandatory but is not used when executing the New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet.

Is this a bug in the creation of the deployment scripting or am I doing something wrong?

@AzureSupport (Twitter) suggested I posted my question here.

Thanks in advance,
Sidney

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong - it's a bug in the script that is offered when you go down the "Automation Script" path in the portal.  You can modify the script to use the parameter or just remove it if you don't use it.

The quickstart repo has more deployment scripts if you want to take a look at those:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for the link to github. it will come in use in the future.